# Handling badly folded long Return-Path header gracefully

Tags: postfix, email-server, pop3, smtp-headers

I've got a problem with my POP3 provider delivering me e-mails with broken `Return-Path` header. When it's long, it gets wrongly folded into multiple lines, in the middle of e-mail address like this:

```
Return-Path: <bounce-md_30050491.5f06fc4d.v1-e20857b41e04493380b808e01cb6b51
 e@mailtracking.gitter.im>
```

Therefore, Postfix returns error and I get bounces from Fetchmail:

```
fetchmail: SMTP error: 501 5.1.7 Bad sender address syntax
```

I've read about Fetchmail's `-Z` option, but I don't want to discard these mails, they are important and not spam.

Is there a possibility to make Postfix treat this special case gracefully and return no error message? Or maybe someone knows a better solution to this problem?

Comment: What king of mailbox do you use?  [ mailbox  (file) / maildir ]

Comment: Maildir is my king! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### fetchmail: direct delivery mailbox/maildir using procmail/maildrop

You can make `fetchamil` use `procmail` (or `maildrop`) to deliver messages directly to mailbox (mailbox file or maildir)  **without sending it via SMTP**.  Your procmail script may even unfold `Return-Path:`.

see `mda`option in [`man fetchmail`](https://www.fetchmail.info/fetchmail-man.html)

I have used similar solution with custom per email account procmail scripts.

---

~/.fetchmailrc

```
poll pop.provider.net proto pop3
  user "jsmith" with pass "secret1"
  mda /usr/bin/procmail -m .procmailrc-provider.net
```

~.procmailrc-provider.net

```
 ########
 # Debugging settings
 ########
 # log all dignostic info to ~/procmail.log
 LOGFILE=procmail.log
 # log abstracts of delivered messages
 # Subject:`,`From:`, size, final destination 
 LOGABSTRACT=all
 # Turn on extended diagnostic
 VERBOSE=on
 ########

 # deliver everttyting to maildir (tailing /) located in directory ~/.maildir 

:0
.maildir/
```

**Debugging:**
fetchamil: `-v` (or even  `-v -v`) command line options
procmail:`LOFILE` and `LOGABSTRACT` settings in procmailrc file

Comment: Thanks. But this method seems to hacky for me. I tried to use Postfix `header_checks` and IGNORE the problematic line with `/^Return-Path: .* /  IGNORE`, but after configuring header checks with `postconf -e 'header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks'` and successful test with `postmap -hmq`, I still get an error. Do you think `header_checks` is a good solution and it's a matter of error in my configuration? Or the idea is for some reason totally bad?

Comment: I am not `postix` expert. I personally prefer making `fetchmail` deliver directly to user's local mailbox  without SMTP server.

Comment: Actually I think I've found out why Postfix does not do header check, by running `fetchmail -v`:
```
fetchmail: SMTP> MAIL FROM:<bounce-mc.us14_64506165.574658-3ac74d0698@mail78.suw151.rsgsv.
 net> SIZE=37416
fetchmail: SMTP< 501 5.1.7 Bad sender address syntax
fetchmail: SMTP error: 501 5.1.7 Bad sender address syntax
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me. maybe I have an error somewhere, I don't know.

Comment: Have you started fetchamil in verbose mode? Do ou want verbose mode hinsts for procmail?

Comment: I've figured it out finally. Turned out I was using `$DEFAULT` variable, which is not present, when firing Procmail this way. Having verbose output was also tricky, but [this guide](http://porkmail.org/era/mail/procmail-debug.html) helped me a lot. I actually used `VERBOSE=yes`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to do could be totally bypass fetchmail and just configure pop3 provider to **forward** all emails to my email address on the server. Unfortunately, my provider does not have this option.